# I can't read date without time from CSV using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
forecasts
Out[15]: 
             timestamp         1            2          
0  2022-11-08 12:12:15         5679.658691  5400.217773  
1  2022-11-08 12:38:49         5679.658691  5400.217773  
2  2022-11-09 11:05:53         5863.616699  5619.101562  
3  2022-11-10 10:46:27         6047.025391  5714.026367  
4  2022-11-11 11:59:29         6147.197754  5750.312988  
5  2022-11-12 11:56:45         6008.574707  5775.820312
```

And I'm trying to get the forecasts on a specific date without including the hour:

```
forecasts = forecasts[forecasts['timestamp'] == pd.Timestamp(str(2022) + '-' + str(11) + '-' + str(11))]
```

to read this date:

```
2022-11-11 11:59:29
```

But I receive an empty `dataframe`. How can I fix that?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Filip i've edited with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
forecasts = forecasts[forecasts['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') == '2022-11-11']
#or
forecasts = forecasts[forecasts['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') == (str(2022) + '-' + str(11) + '-' + str(11))]
```

Comment: still empty dataframe

Comment: Can you check it again ?

Comment: it still empty, with 00:00:00 added it will still look for this timestamp that can't find. the idea is to ignore the time completely

Comment: Ok, now I believe I got it right. Can you check it please.